# Update specific column of given list in ORMLite

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, orm, ormlite-servicestack

Below ORMLite API will update given records (given list) based on the primary key.

`db.UpdateAll<Student>(lstStudent);`

But, what if I need to update a specific column (let say standard from 3rd to 4th) of all given student list. This will not send additional data (that we actually do not want to update) on the network to the db server.

Is there any API provided by ORMLite to update specific column(s) of given IEnumerable object? I am looking for something like UpdateOnlyAll (just like what we have UpdateOnly() for Update() API).